# Set the header for PDF document on second page

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have a jsp page that contains some data(This data may very because it is fetches from the data base) over it.Now I am generating the PDF file for the my jsp page using the ‘Itext api’ . Now I need to set the some specific header  on this generated pages started from the Page 2 onwards.
**For Ex :-**

**Test.jsp**

```
Jsp test page contains the data for testing purpose.
```

**Test.pdf**

```
    Jsp test page contains the data for testing purpose.
    ……
    …

Page 1 ends
Page 2 starts
```

**My title for the page**..(Only needed for the second page onwards)**

Please help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can probably make use of `setSkipFirstHeader(boolean)` of `PdfPTable`.  Which will not print out the first occurrence of the header of your table.  You will need to be sure to setHeaderRows on the table.

You could also subclass the [PdfPageEventHelper](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEventHelper.html) and in the onEndPage event, use the passed in Document object to [getPageNumber()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#getPageNumber%28%29).  When you determine it is past the first page, you can add your header content to the document.